# Javascript Alert Reporting two different Window Heights

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a very bizzare thing I am trying to solve.

Currently I am loading all of this at the end of my page and when I first load the page it alerts 571 and on a refresh it alerts 627. Whereas if I move this all to the `<head>` tag it alerts 627 every time and that is the correct value.

Can anyone see why loading this at the end of a page would lead to a wrong smaller window height?

```
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

var Height = $(window).height()-40;
$("#section1").css('min-height',Height);
$("#section2").css('min-height',Height);
alert(Height);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you use? Do you have a live example where I can see this behavior? If no, could you create one (perhaps on jsfiddle.net)? Does this only occur with a specific browser, or with all you tested? Which browsers did you test?

Comment: Good questions. I will get back to you and edit this comment with all the answers in a second

Comment: so, what is 56 pixel high in your page?

Comment: I'd say he has an image in his page with no set height. So race condition on load, sometimes the height is without the img, sometimes with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously I have no clue why this happens. To find out I would definitely need the code of the whole page or a working live example.

But in your case I would just use `$(window).load` instead of ready.

```
<script> 
$(window).load(function() {

var Height = $(window).height()-40;
$("#section1").css('min-height',Height);
$("#section2").css('min-height',Height);
alert(Height);

});
</script>
```